# Add to each enumerable a calculated value

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to fetch "work_items" from the database, calculate a value, add it to the respective work_item and then continue, but I can't figure out why it does not work:

```
import Ecto.query, warn: false

  def list_work_items do
    WorkItem
    |> select_merge([work_item], %{value: ^work_item_value(work_item)})
    |> Repo.all()
  end

  defp work_item_value(work_item) do
    work_item.duration_in_minutes/60 * work_item.hourly_rate_in_cents
  end
```

When I run `mix phx.server` I get:

```
warning: variable "work_item" does not exist and is being expanded to "work_item()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  lib/fourty/tracking.ex:22: Fourty.Tracking.list_work_items/0


== Compilation error in file lib/fourty/tracking.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/fourty/tracking.ex:22: undefined function work_item/0
...
```

`22` is the one with the `select_merge`.

I have googelt and tried the docs, but can't figure out why it does not work. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think what's going on is that you're hitting a snag with trying to pin a function call.  Instead of this `^work_item_value(work_item)` try storing the output of that function and pinning the result so it looks more like  `result = work_item_value(work_item)` and  `^result`
It would be easier to see what's going on if you fixed your formatting -- thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out - the solution is to use a virtual field:

`field :value, :float, virtual: true`

and then use:

```
  def list_work_items do
    WorkItem
    |> select_merge([work_item], %{value: fragment("?/60 * ?"), work_item.duration_in_minutes, work_item.hourly_rate_in_cents})
    |> Repo.all()
  end
```

Comment: Good answer! I would argue that the fragment should be `fragment("?/60 * ?", work_item.duration_in_minutes, work_item.hourly_rate_in_cents)` to ensure that the correct table alias is used.

Comment: I like that - modified! Thanks for the input! :)